# What word describes something that can move orthogonally and diagonally?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the union of orthogonal and diagonal? If used in a sentence:

> The queen in chess can move ______.

And used in another sentence:

> There are infinitely many directions. My pet robot can only move vertically, horizontally, or diagonally at 45 degree angles (a total of eight uniformly distributed directions). My pet robot can move ______.

The rules for chess describe the queen as able to move vertically, horizontally or diagonally. Just as vertically and horizontally can be condensed into a single word, orthogonally, I was hoping to condense all three to a single word.

Comment: You can say the queen can move in [all *cardinal and ordinal*, or in any of the *eight principle*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_winds#Compass_point_names), directions.

Comment: The queen can move any direction the king can move, only farther.

Comment: *Octopussianly*, while not in any dictionary, is evocative.

Comment: **@Rainbolt**: I need clarification on what you are asking for. Your example of the pet robot confuses the issue. Are you asking for this word in a chess-like or chess-only context (grid-based 8 directions max) or for ALL "orthogonal and diagonal" movement including non-45° angles ("infinite directions")? If the former than the mouthful of **octilinearly** as suggested below by Jimi Oke fits well indeed. If the latter then I humbly submit my **radially** usage below.

Comment: On an aside, the use of the word "vertically" is somewhat in error as that would imply Z-axis motion akin to levitation ("my pet robot has antigrav boosters"). Of course if you are referring to [3D chess or Star Trek chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28text_game%29) then vertically is a possible movement direction for **all** of the pieces.

Comment: Can future readers please refrain from posting answers in the comments? If you have a worthwhile answer, post it as an answer. @O.M.Y I've edited the question to address your second comment. If I have not succeeded, let me know.

Comment: @andy256: why *octopussian*? Don't octopuses tend to move in whatever direction they want :)

Comment: *In 8 directions* although in other games *like a queen in chess* is the usual descriptor.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have been doing some academic research in this area. The current coinage, which I think perfectly applies to the movement of the queen in chess, is *octilinear*. This term has been used to describe metro-map layouts that have followed Harry Beck's paradigm. The vertices of a unit-spaced octilinear grid describe the queen's range of motion (in multiples of 45 degrees; four axes and eight possible directions). So, to complete your sentence:

> The queen in chess can move octilinearly.

[image: Octilinear grid]

The most recent journal paper in the schematic mapping field is: [*Octilinear Force-Directed Layout with Mental Map Preservation for Schematic Diagrams*](https://kar.kent.ac.uk/41428/1/diagrams14-force.pdf). And a search on Google scholar will show that *octilinear* is now a widely-accepted term, that hopefully will move into mainstream vocabulary!

Comment: But that applies in a 2-dimensional world. What would it be called in 3D, or even better - nD?

Comment: @KonradViltersten In all honesty, that's a technical question about mathematics or engineering, and not about English, since I doubt such term is widely used in any language. Maybe [Mathematics.SE] would be a better place for it?

Comment: @yo'Well, the reply I was commenting on opened for the scientific lingo, so I felt it was called for. But generally speaking, I agree with you. It's so seldom used that there's little risk there's an non-mathematical term for it anyway.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Great question! I have no idea what the appropriate term might be in n dimensions...

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is a coinage opportunity, although perhaps, given that *octolinear* has sneaked in first, a fading one.

As a straightforward composition in the German tradition of piling together existing words, we could say that a queen moves ***orthodiagonally***. As [Scott Centoni](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/74572/scott-centoni) observed, this might support extension into higher dimensions also.

---

As an imagery-based coinage to support the idea of the queen's move to other applications, you could say that the queen in chess moves ***majestically***. So does the king, but more slowly.

And then [Jimi Oke](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2705/jimi-oke)'s referenced paper could talk about about *Majestic Force-Directed Layout*...

Comment: I'm having fun conjuring up images of a pet robot moving majestically.

Comment: **@Joffan**: While I love your suggestion for its creativity I do not think it will fly. :( On the other hand I was inspired to my own "coinage opportunity" by your post, albeit a more pedestrian one involving re-purposing an adjective to a new usage as an adverb. See above.

Comment: *Majestically* is cute, but I like *orthodiagonally* better than *octalinearly* because it does generalize better for arbitrary dimensions >=2.

Comment: @ScottCentoni Interesting... how many directions would you say are orthodiagonal in three dimensions? 18 or 26?

Comment: Definitely not *majestically* but I do like *orthodiagonally*!

Comment: @JimiOke - yes... I rearranged my answer to promote the constructive over the allegorical coinage :-)

Comment: @JimiOke ***octanormally***?

Comment: Or *octagonally*? *Octanormally* could be dissected by the geometric types to mean something different..

Comment: Probably no end to possible constructions but I like your rearrangement :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20878/discussion-between-jimi-oke-and-joffan).

Answer (score 1):

***octagonal*** neighbors/directions/moves

In the 15th century, mathematicians decided to combine Greek words with Latin flavoring to form new terms, and they came up with:

- from dia- "across/through" + gōnia "angle/corner" => **diagonal**
- from ortho- "straight" + gōnia => **orthogonal**

and similarly

- from okta- combining form of okto "eight" + gōnia => **octagonal**

I wonder why we refused to assign relational/spacial meaning to word *octagonal* and only use it for describing shape of things. The way this word was formed is identical to the other siblings, and we are happy with diagonal and orthogonal directions. I stand for *octagonal* directions. Poor guy deserved it :)

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better (i.e. existing) word, I'd probably use *[octantally](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/octantal)*

Comment: I gotta give you credit for dredging that one up.

Comment: "Octant" usually means the three-dimensional analogue of a quadrant. I'd be confused by such usage.

Comment: Interesting word, I could have used that many years ago when I was tinkering with programming [Star Trek games in BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28text_game%29). :)

Answer (score 0):

How about "[**radially**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/radially)" ?

Technically this word is an adjective but I see no reason why it could not be applied as an adverb in this context per the first part of definition #3 below.

adjective

1. arranged like radii or rays.
2. having spokes, bars, lines, etc., arranged like radii, as a machine.
3. **made in the direction of a radius; going from the center outward** or from the circumference inward along a radius: a radial cut.

Comment: "radially" is a perfectly good adverb already , and not a bad choice,  although its association with circles does mean that I think of the possible directions as unlimited rather than restricted to 8. But don't let my mathematical background slow you down. :-)

Comment: Mathematically speaking, it's too relaxed. Consider the horie's move. Effectively, it moves **radially** too but it's eight direction are not equidistantly spread (or, even more exact, they are offset from the queen's movement angles by an angle).

Comment: Strictly speaking, every piece moves radially, only the angle of said radius is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the term "Holonomic" from the robotics realm.

If you have a robot base that can move in any direction from any orientation, this type of drive is often called holonomic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_(robotics)

Comment: Total degrees of freedom in the robotics realm: infinite. Degrees of freedom of the robot in the question: eight. Therefore, the robot in my question is *not* holonomic.

Comment: @Rainbolt 45-degrees-increment-based-holonomic, then? There's probably some weird planet where this term is commonly used, hehe.

Comment: @KonradViltersten How about holonomic-but-not-really?

Comment: @Rainbolt Naa, no way. You're loosing the oh-so-crucial information about equidistant partitioning into eight available directions. (Seriously, though, I believe your term is much less eye-brows-raisable, hehe.)

Answer (score 0):

A short phrase might be ***in a straight line***.

If you want a single word, how about ***queen-style***?

> While there are infinitely many directions, your pet robot can only move queen-style.

Of course, this doesn't work when describing Chess rules.

Comment: I like *queen-style*. I don't like *in a straight line*. It doesn't limit direction to only eight possibilities.