# A word to describe vertical and horizontal movement?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine the 'Bishop' chess piece. The four directions that it can move can be called 'diagonal'.

Similarly the 'Castle' moves in the horizontal and vertical directions. Is there a single word that describes this movement?

Comment: This "related question" actually mentions this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225378/what-word-describes-something-that-can-move-orthogonally-and-diagonally?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) in chess moves ***orthogonally***.

This term is not used often (unlike *diagonally*) as more authors seem to prefer to spell things out (i.e., *horizontally and vertically*) to prevent being misunderstood. Still, it can be traced in many chess manuals, such as [this one](http://theroutiers.org/archive/articles/1640_chess.pdf) (cf. *Basic play* section, p. 2).

[*Orthogonal*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orthogonal)  literally means "along angles", while [*diagonal*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=diagonal) means "across angles", where the word [*angle*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-gon) needs to be understood as "the right angle".

Comment: Is it really so? Doesn't _orthogonally_ mean to move at a right angle to something? But the rook only moves straight in one direction.

Comment: @MartinPeters _Orthogonal_ is quite often used the way you propose (i.e., _orthogonal to something_), often to mean _independent_. That's fine, there is however no reason to insist on exclusively this usage.

Comment: The bishop Moves orthogonally as well, according to most definitions of ortHogonal I'm familiar with.

Comment: @aquirdturtle "The bishop has no restrictions in distance for each move, but is limited to diagonal movement." [Wikipedia, Bishop (chess)].

Comment: @anemone Hm, maybe I am biased with regard to the meaning of _orthogonal_ being a mathematician.

Comment: @MartinPeters As it happens, I'm a mathematician too. I find the word streamlined, and it is supported by numerous examples. I am not saying it is what comes immediately to mind w.r.t. chess (as opposed to diagonal, which is used widely), but that's what the question is about, I gather.

Comment: @aquirdturtle: the bishop's two directions of movement are orthogonal to *each other*, but diagonal *to the rows and columns of the chessboard.* Both "orthogonal" and "diagonal" require a reference to have unambiguous meaning, right?

Comment: @sumelic - agreed; if diagonal has an accepted, implied reference, then there should be no problem in using orthogonal in the same manner. (By the way, the bishop has four 'directions of movement', no?)

Comment: @JHCL: hmm, I guess I was mentally combining opposing pairs of directions. We could say that two of them are just negative movements in the opposite direction.

Comment: yes, fair point.

Comment: I down-voted this. Orthogonal does *not* imply horizontal and vertical movement. Orthogonal implies that one movement is at a right angle with respect to the other. Horizontal and diagonal movements are thus always orthogonal, but two diagonal movements can also be orthogonal to each other. In fact, the two diagonal movements in chess are orthogonal to each other. The fact that a book on chess assumes a one-way usage of the word does not change its definition. That is a fallacy.

Comment: @JJMDriessen Thanks for your message. I really appreciate you left a note with your downvote. You will perhaps do me the favour of visiting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippogonal or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece#Notations for further reference for the term I am proposing.

Comment: @JJMDriessen: Are you sure you want to downvote? "The rook in chess moves in orthogonal directions" is a different sentence from "The rook in chess moves orthogonally." In the second sentence, it seems to me that there is an implied extension "... to the direction of the rows and columns of the board." Same as with "the bishop moves diagonally (relative to the rows and columns)." Otherwise, what would "the bishop moves diagonally" even mean?

Answer (score -1):

How about **translation** (in the mathematical sense)? i.e. both types of movements are examples of translations of the chess pieces

EDIT: oh **excluding** the diagonal. Ignore me XD

Comment: translation would include diagonal movement however

Comment: What do you think of "edge parallel"?

Comment: Oh I missed that it was excluding the diagonal T.T

Comment: If you've made a mistake, that's fine. You can delete your own answer and leave a comment under the question with this information.